# Top items in javascript show/hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How I can do that so there will be read "Show Top 10 items" and when I click it it shows "Hide Top 10 items"

My code

```
// TOP 10 items

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT items1, items2, items3 FROM items");

    if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {

    print ("<a href=\"javascript: klappe_news('a4')\">Show Top 10 Items</a>
           <div style='display:none'>
           <table align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'><tr>
           <td>Items1</td>
           <td>Items2</td>
           <td>Items3</td>
        </tr>");

   while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    print ("<tr>
           <td>".$arr['items1']."</td>
           <td>".$arr['items2']."</td>
           <td>".$arr['items3']."</td>
        </tr>");
    }

    print("</table></div>");
    } ?>
```

Comment: Your page is being served with the top 10 so this is a question about toggling the visibility of an element using _JavaScript_? In which case; this is not a question about _PHP_

Answer (score 2):

For mysql you have to use something like that

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT items1, items2, items3 FROM items LIMIT 10 ");
```

Answer (score -1):

This has to be done with jQuery or javascript.

```
// TOP 10 items

$results = mysql_query("SELECT items1, items2, items3 FROM items");

if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
//You have to add an id to <a> to access it with jQuery
//You also need to add an id to the div
print ("<a id="show_hide" href=\"javascript: klappe_news('a4')\">Show Top 10 Items</a>
       <div id="table_container" style='display:none'>
       <table align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'><tr>
       <td>Items1</td>
       <td>Items2</td>
       <td>Items3</td>
    </tr>");

while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

print ("<tr>
       <td>".$arr['items1']."</td>
       <td>".$arr['items2']."</td>
       <td>".$arr['items3']."</td>
    </tr>");
}

print("</table></div>");
} ?>
<!-- Add jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Click event
    $('#show_hide').click(function() {
        //Hides the div with id table_container
        $('#table_container').toggle();

        //Checks if div with id table_container is visble, then it hides or shows it and changes the text
        if($('#table_container').is(':visible'))
            $(this).html('Hide Top 10 Items');
        else
            $(this).html('Show Top 10 Items');
    });

</script>
```

You might have a problem with the page because you are using an  tag, every time you click on it, it will reload the page, so you might need to switch it to a div.

EDIT:
I forgot to add jQuery